# Pasadena - Mobile sightings data

Tags: data-request

US Department of Transportation is offering different data sets for research on mobility. Unfortunately, one of those data sources, have been removed because "US DOT currently does not have the rights to distribute this data set"

https://www.its-rde.net/data/showdf?dataSetNumber=10055

Does anyone know is this data set available elsewhere?

BR
Toni